# Wrong number of args passed to keyword when using recur

Tags: recursion, clojure

I'm novice to Clojure. Here is my code:

```
(defn startgame [room-id]
  (loop [rid room-id]
    (println (clojure.string/join " "(get-room-description rid)))
      (let [rid (keyword (read-line))]
        (if (= rid :0)
          "bye bye"
          (recur (rid)))
  )))
```

It compiles fine, but when running it when it reach `recur(rid)` line, it throws error: 
`IllegalArgumentException Wrong number of args passed to keyword: :1  clojure.lang.Keyword.throwArity (Keyword.java:97)`

I spent last few hours to find what cause it, but I can't find solution. My loop has one argument `rid` so `recur` should have one?

Comment: What is `get-room-description`?

Comment: it's another function which is getting element from the map based on key. Similar to (get key map), but I don't need to pass map as parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defn startgame [room-id]
  (loop [rid room-id]
    (let [rid (keyword (read-line))]
      (if (= rid :0)
        "bye bye"
        (recur rid)))))
```

Don't need parentheses for `rid`.

`rid` is `clojure.lang.Keyword` type, so we can't use this variable as a function(in this case / sometimes you can use keyword as a function like this `(:foo {:foo 10}) ;;=> 10` ).

Comment: So why every example I could find in official docs have parentheses? I can't believe it was so simple. OK. I see it now. if there is some kind of expression then () are required.

Comment: Let's consider following exmaple. `(loop [cnt 0] (if (= cnt 10) "bye bye" (do (println cnt) (recur (inc cnt)))))` . This is simple recursive example, we want to count up `cnt` variable to 10 from 0, so we need to increment `cnt` variable before passing to `recur` function. So that's why we need `()` sometimes.